# codeigniter load model use get parameters

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I use Three DB Server and One Application Server.

```
class Main extends REST_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        if($this->input->get('country', true) == "KR")
        {
            $krdb['host'] = '11.22.33.44';
            //blah blah

            $this->load->model('category', '', $krdb);
            $this->load->model('contents', '', $krdb);
            $this->load->model('user', '', $krdb);
            $this->load->model('series', '', $krdb);
        }
        else if($this->input->get('country', true) == "EN")
        {
            $endb['host'] = '111.222.33.44';
            //blah blah

            $this->load->model('category', '', $endb);
            $this->load->model('contents', '', $endb);
            $this->load->model('user', '', $endb);
            $this->load->model('series', '', $endb);
        }

    }
}
```

but this run, can't load db.

if change condition if(1==1), right active.

my guess, call Controller construct function before get parameters setting

please help me..

Answer (score 1):

In your `config/database.php` your database is configured to the `'default'` group, like so:

```
<?php

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'host';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database';
This allows you to specify other groups like this:

$db['KR']['hostname'] = 'host';
$db['KR']['username'] = 'username';
$db['KR']['password'] = 'password';
$db['KR']['database'] = 'database';

$db['EN']['hostname'] = 'host';
$db['EN']['username'] = 'username';
$db['EN']['password'] = 'password';
$db['EN']['database'] = 'database';
You can then connect to another database by using:
```

**IN controller**

```
class Main extends REST_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        if ($this->input->get('country', true) == "KR") {
            $defaultDB = $this->load->database('KR', TRUE);
        } else if ($this->input->get('country', true) == "EN") {
           $defaultDB = $this->load->database('EN', TRUE);
        }else{
              $defaultDB = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks to answer. but, when i tried this way, no change. how change $this->load->model('category', '', $endb); this code??

Comment: Message : file_get_contents failed to open stream. 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: its means its working fine. you need to check your file_get_contents code

Comment: I don't understand.. when set one database, It work good. but, select dynamic, show this error

Comment: you database problem is correct . now accept this answer. for Further error put a new question for this with error message and error code